# Jade mixin iteration json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug, mixins

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "leadership": [
    {
        "leadername": "Name1",
        "leaderjob": "Chairman",
        "leaderdescription": "The boss"
    },
    {
        "leadername": "Name2",
        "leaderjob": "Chief Executive Officer",
        "leaderdescription": "Other boss"
    }
  ]
}
```

and if I try to get the content with the following mixin:

```
mixin defList(obj)
  dl.deflist
    each item in obj
      dt= item.leadername
      dd= item.leaderdescription
```

by calling it like this

```
+defList(leadership)
```

everything works fine, but what I would like to have is this:

```
mixin defList(obj, name, description)
    dl.deflist
        each item in obj
           dt= name
           dd= description
```

so I would be able to call it like this:

```
+defList(leadership, leadername, leaderdescription)
```

but unfortunately I get only empty dt and dd tags.

Is there any way to make it work and populate the list?
I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, you would solve like this:

```
mixin defList(obj, name, description)
  dl.deflist
    each item in obj
      dt= item[name]
      dd= item[description]
```

then:

```
+defList(leadership, "leadername", "leaderdescription")
```

Result:

```
<dl class="deflist"><dt>Name1</dt><dd>The boss</dd><dt>Name2</dt><dd>Other boss</dd></dl>
```